# If value in list in Python programming

Tags: python, list, if-statement, text-files

I need to be able to check for two things, if the item they have chosen is in the list and also if they can essentially afford the item in comparison to their bank balance which needs to change whenever something is purchased.

I am reading from a text file to get my list and seem to be having some trouble doing so as whenever i enter a piece of information from the list it says its not in it.

```
with open("items.txt") as f:
    items = f.readlines()

print(items)

item = input("Please enter a item from the list")

if item in items:
    print("Thank you, you have selected", item)

else:
    print("That item is not in the list")
    item = input("Please enter the item again")
```

Comment: Can you give us some code?

Comment: Exactly what kind of help are you expecting without showing any code? What are we supposed to fix?

Comment: sorry i didnt know how to post code as the formatting wasn't correct i will try now

Comment: Just try, I can edit it, if formatting goes wrong.

Comment: dont worry about the bank bit for now, this was the code i was trying to use for checking if its in the list which was the main issue.

with open("items.txt") as f:
    items = f.readlines()

print(items)

item = input("Please enter a item from the list")

if item in items:
    print("Thank you, you have selected", item)

else:
    print("That item is not in the list")
    item = input("Please enter the item again")

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not in the use of `in`; it is in the values you return from the file. Each item in `items` is an entire line read from the file, *including the newline character*. You need to strip that off before comparing.

```
with open("items.txt") as f:
    items = [line.strip('\n') for line in f]
```

Answer (score 1):

Too little information, but You probably need some like this:

### in list

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

item = 4
print item in list
True

item = 7
print item in list
False
```

### comparsion

```
bank = 3
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print [item for item in list if item >= bank]
[3, 4, 5]
```